# Is there a difference in runtime if a heavy calculations function is in the conditional part of the loop?

Tags: c++, performance, runtime

Is there a difference in runtime if a heavy calculations is in the conditional part of the loop?

For example:

```
int i,n;
for(i=1;i<=[call to some complex function on n];i++)
...
```

Or

```
int i,n,foo;
foo=[call to some complex function on n];
for(i=1;i<=foo;i++)
...
```

Which one is more efficient? does the loop make the calculation once or with each iteration?

Comment: The loop will evaluate the expression every time in the first example.

Comment: I'm not an expert on this topic, but I believe it is slower using it in the condition if it is not constant (and so can't be computed compile-time). If it has something to do with any variables, it has to re-evaluate every time.

Comment: @Pietu1998 so if the value for n will be entered after compiling then there isn't going to be any difference?

Comment: @kuhaku Partially rewrote the comment, I originally wrote the opposite of what I was thinking of. It's slower to put it in the condition if n is entered after compilation.

Comment: This is just as much of a readability optimization as a performance one. I think a lot of people would agree that the second example is more readable if the "complex function" is really long or is an ugly expression.

Comment: @Mysticial having a built in function like `pow` is more nice IMO in the first example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, there will be a "performance hit" for functions provided in the conditional part of a `for` loop *unless* the function is const and the compiler can reduce it down to a constant value.  The compiler will need to call the function for each iteration.

I highly recommend placing the result of the function into a constant temporary variable before entering the loop.

Example:

```
const unsigned int limit = my_vector.size();
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < limit; ++i)
{
  // iterate over vector
}
```

Comment: Agreed with this, but, there is another aspect to be considered. Certain, STL containers do not have a O(1) size() methods. For them, having the size() fetched and saved before the loop, becomes nearly mandatory as opposed to just being nice-to-have.

Answer (score 1):

It is best to measure: that's the common-denominator advice :-)

But, reasoning about it logically from a code generation perspective:

If the second operand of the relational expression is identifiable by the compiler as a loop-invariant expression, it can safely perform code motion. You would reap all the benefits as if you manually did it.

Loop-Invariant code identification is subject to some constraints, including, not limited to:

1. Loop index itself is not participating in the expression.
2. Usually, any pointers can throw off the compiler, as it won't be able to reason.
3. If the expression involves a variable that is "def"ed inside the loop body, it is a no-go.

Points #1 and #3 are not applicable, if you are able to manually able to move it out - meaning there are no data dependencies.

Regarding the performance differential, it depends on the cost. I have come across a code review, where someone inadvertently made an algorithm O(n^2) exactly due to the condition expression in the loop.

It is great that you are paying attention to it.